# Generating test data for functional tests

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf, testing, test-data

I need to generate some test data for a Web and WPF application (both .NET Apps). So I had two possible solution in my mind.

1. Generate test data by using sql scripts. This approach has the issue that I need to validate the inserted data.
2. Use the insert API of my .NET code to generate test data. For this I am not sure if its oversized, but I would reuse the validation logic of my code.

Do you have any other suggestions? Maybe Microsoft tools for supporting those creation tasks?

Thanks!
Oliver

Comment: Did you use Entity Framework Code First in the web?

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use sql/db in your test. It is extra dependency that has nothing to do of your program logic. Normally, I would create an interface called IDataProvider and then provide different implementation i.e. DbDataProvider for normal execution or FakeDataProvdier for testing. With that IDataProvider interface, means that you can plug into whatever datasource your want for your testing e.g. TextFile, xml, json, objectbuilder using your own api etc.
2. Using insert API for generating test data is a better idea. But, why would you worry about performing validation to your test data ? Normally, a test should failed if the test data is wrong or you are not doing right functional test.

Comment: Thanks @cscmh99 for your suggestion. Maybe I did not explain my worry about the validation correctly. The functional test will be run by a tester but the test data will be generated by a developer. So I just worry about, how to generate valid test data with all dependencies. A solution would be to use the existing API, but I am not sure if its the best way...